# How to prove $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x+1}{2x+3}\neq 2$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to prove that $$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x+1}{2x+3}\ne2$$ when using the epsilion-delta definition. As I understand I need to find $\varepsilon>0$ which $\forall\delta>0\ \exists x$ so $0<|x-2|<\delta$ that $|f(x)-2|\geqslant\varepsilon$.

What I tried - lets take $\varepsilon = 1$ so we get:
$$\begin{align*}|f(x)-2|<1&\iff\left|\frac{x+1}{2x+3}-2\right|<1\\& \iff\left|\frac{x+1-4x-6}{2x+3}\right|<1\\& \iff\left|\frac{-3x-5}{2x+3}\right|<1\end{align*}$$
and then we get $x>-\frac33$ and $x<-\frac85$. But how to continue?

Comment: So what would be the delta in this case? Would it exist?

Comment: You are supposed to prove that $\left|\dfrac{3x+5}{2x+3}\right|\geq 1$ for values of $x$ near $2$. This is obvious if $x>0$. Done!! I really don't understand why students start solving inequalities in $\epsilon, \delta$ proofs and thereby complicate a much simpler problem.

Comment: Most answers here have also tried to go the complicated way. Not everything has to be made difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track in terms of understanding that you need to prove that there exists an $\epsilon\gt0$ such that for all $\delta\gt0$ there exists an $x$ such that $0\lt|x-2|\lt\delta$ and $\left|{x+1\over2x+3}-2\right|\ge\epsilon$. (Note, I changed your "that" to an "and" between the delta and epsilon inequalities at the end of the sentence.) And your choice of $\epsilon=1$ turns out to be OK. All you really need to do to complete the proof is to let $x=2+\delta'$ with $0\lt\delta'\lt\delta$ (say $\delta'=\delta/2$), so that $0\lt|x-2|\lt\delta$ is guaranteed, and show that

$$\left|{(2+\delta')+1\over2(2+\delta')+3}-2 \right|\ge1$$

which is easy to do, since

$$\left|{(2+\delta')+1\over2(2+\delta')+3}-2 \right|=\left|-11-3\delta'\over7+2\delta' \right|$$

and $11+3\delta'\gt7+2\delta'$ for any positive $\delta'$.

Remark: There are other ways of showing that the limit cannot be $2$, using general theorems about manipulating limits, but you asked for an approach using the epsilon-delta definition and you were on your way to doing so when you got lost in the logic, which is easy to do when there is a string of quantifiers. It's well worth getting some experience fighting your way through a thicket of definitional $\forall$s and $\exists$s, if only to appreciate life when you have more powerful theorems at your fingertips.

Answer (score 2):

I am expanding my comments into an answer. The trigger for this action is the existence of complicated answers (almost every one so far) to a very simple problem.

You start off correctly by choosing the correct value of $\epsilon =1$. Good guess! Now prove that your guess works. We have $$|f(x) - 2|=\left|\frac{3x+5}{2x+3}\right|=\left|1+\frac{x+2}{2x+3}\right|$$ and obviously this is greater than $1$ if $x>0$.

Now every neighborhood of $2$ of the form $(2-\delta,2+\delta)$ contains some positive $x$ (another obvious fact) and for that value of $x$ you have $|f(x) - 2|>1$. This completes the proof that $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)\neq 2$.

I don't see the point of calculations made in other answers when the obviousness of the solution is staring us right from the front.

---

The guess for $\epsilon$ in such cases is made by choosing $\epsilon$ to be less than difference between the proposed limit and one of *the actual limit points of the function* under consideration. In this case the function has a limit $3/7$ and that is its only limit point. So any value of $\epsilon$ with $0<\epsilon<|3/7-2|$ will work. $\epsilon=1$ makes things much simpler.

Next problem is to identify the trouble points (which reverse the target inequality in definition of limits) and show that every neighborhood of $c$ (in case of $\lim_{x\to c} $) includes at least one such point. In other words $c$ is a limit point of such troublesome points.

Luckily in this problem we identified one set of such trouble points as $\mathbb{R}^{+} =(0,\infty) $ in a very obvious manner. And clearly $2$ is a limit point of this interval.

---

**Clarification**: By *actual limit point of a function* in context of a limit operation like $x\to c$ I mean a number $L$ for which a sequence $\{x_n\} $ exists with $x_n\neq c, x_n\to c$ and $f(x_n) \to L$. For example when analyzing $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(1/x)$ one can prove that the set of limit points of $f(x) =\sin (1/x)$ here is $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll do it another way. I'll prove $$\lim_{x \to 2}\left(\frac{x+1}{2x+3}\right)=\frac{3}{7}$$
By proving that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$
$$0<|x-2|<\delta \implies \left|\left(\frac{x+1}{2x+3}\right)-\frac{3}{7}\right|<\epsilon$$
$$\left|\left(\frac{x+1}{2x+3}\right)-\frac{3}{7}\right|=\frac{|x - 2|}{14 | x + 1.5|}$$
Now if we restrtict $|x-2|<\delta \iff -\delta+3.5<x+1.5<\delta+3.5 \implies  |x+1.5|>-\delta+3.5$ thus
$$\frac{|x - 2|}{14 | x + 1.5|}<\frac{\delta}{49-14\delta}$$
suggesting we take $\frac{\delta}{49-14\delta}= \epsilon \iff \delta=\frac{49\epsilon}{14\epsilon+1}$

Now the proof:
let $\epsilon >0$ and set $\delta=\frac{49\epsilon}{14\epsilon+1}$, and since $\epsilon >0$ then for sure $14\epsilon+1 \ne 0$
$$|x-2|< \delta$$
$$\implies |x+1.5|>-\delta+3.5 \implies \frac{1}{14|x+1.5|}<\frac{1}{49-14\delta}$$
So multplying the above two inequalities, we get
$$\frac{|x-2|}{14|x+1.5|}<\frac{\delta}{49-14\delta}$$
Now substituting $\delta =\frac{49}{14\epsilon+1}$ and simplifying we get
$$|\frac{x-2}{14x+21}|<\frac{\frac{49}{14\epsilon+1}}{49-14\cdot\frac{49}{14\epsilon+1}}$$
$$\implies \left|\left(\frac{x+1}{2x+3}\right)-\frac{3}{7}\right|<
\frac{\frac{49\epsilon}{14\epsilon+1}}{49-14\cdot\frac{49\epsilon}{14\epsilon+1}}=\frac{49\epsilon}{49(14\epsilon +1)-14\cdot49\epsilon}=
\frac{\epsilon}{14\epsilon +1-14\epsilon}=\epsilon$$
Does this proof do it?

Answer (score 0):

I always like to let my limits approach 0, so let $x = y+2$.
Then

$\dfrac{x+1}{2x+3}
=\dfrac{y+3}{2y+7}
$

and,
since it looks like this approaches
$\dfrac37$,

$\dfrac{y+3}{2y+7}-\dfrac37
=\dfrac{7(y+3)-3(2y+7)}{7(2y+7)}
=\dfrac{y}{7(2y+7)}
$

so,
if $|y| < 1$,

$|\dfrac{y+3}{2y+7}-\dfrac37|
=|\dfrac{y}{7(2y+7)}|
\lt |\dfrac{y}{35}|
$.

The rest should be easy.